# How to do a SQL SELECT query with a JOIN that doesn't use the key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-migration

I've changed the design of my database, let's say that the old design was like this:

```
tableA (keyA, atrA1, atrA2, atrA3)
tableB (keyB, atrB1)
tableC (keyC, atrA1, atrA2, atrB1, atrC1, atrC2)
```

The new design is:

```
tableA (keyA, atrA1, atrA2, atrA3)
tableB (keyB, atrB1)
tableCNew (keyC, keyA(Foreign Key), keyB(Foreign Key), atrC1, atrC2)
```

Just to be clear, it is guaranteed that there is a unique keyA for each combination of atrA1 and atrA2 (I mean, there aren't repeated values in the database). The same goes for atrB1, no duplicates in the entire table.

What I want to do is a SQL query that inserts all the values of tableC into tableCNew.

So, for each row of tableC, I need to find the keyA for atrA1 and atrA2 and the keyB for atrB1, and then, insert the obtained keyA and the keyB along with the old values of atrC1 and atrC2 into tableCNew. Also, I would like to do this in a single SQL query.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no requirement that joins be made using keys. Sure, that's usually how they're done, but you can join on anything (that's one of the big positives of a relational database).

Simply join tableC to the other two tables using the attribute columns to create your insertion data:

```
insert into tableNew
select keyC, keyA, keyB, atrC1, atrC2
from tableC c
join tableA a on a.atrA1 = c.atrA1 and a.atrA2 = c.atrA2
join tableB b on b.atrB1 = c.atrB1
```